# how to Print Data from Database in jTable that contained a space

Tags: java

i'm trying to print my data in database from jTable, for example in the column of name

```
Jackson demarie

Calvin Dkelein

Tom Enderson
```

but when i **convert it to .pdf or print it**, it become  messy,because of the appearing of the unknown irregular spacing   like this

```
Jackson          demarie

Calvin        Dkelein

Tom               Enderson
```

here my code for inserting into database in server's side:

```
 public String insertPJG(String Nama_PJG,String Gugus)throws RemoteException
    {
        int rowsAffected=0;
        String sReturn="insert failed";
        try
        {
           Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
           con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:PKKP","","");
           CallableStatement prepstmt = con.prepareCall("{call insertPJG(?,?)}");
           prepstmt.setString(1, Nama_PJG);
           prepstmt.setString(2, Gugus);
           rowsAffected=prepstmt.executeUpdate();
           if(rowsAffected>0)
           {
               sReturn="insert success";
           }

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

            System.out.println("Error at insert :"+ex.getMessage());


        }
        return sReturn;

    }
```

and here my code for inserting into database in client's side:

```
 private void jAddActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
    try
   {
  server serv = (server)Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/server");
  //validasi
  String nama= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Name").trim();
  String Gugus= "";

  while(flag)
  {
      if (!nama.equals(""))
      {

        Gugus=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Gugus");

            if (!Gugus.equals(""))
            {

                    String insert=serv.insertPJG(nama, Gugus);
                    System.out.println(insert);
                    if(insert.equals("insert success"))
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "inserted");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "insert failed");

                    }
              flag= false;

            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Please provide the Grup  ", "input invalid", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
                Gugus= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Gugus");

            }


      }
      else
      {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Please provide the Name  ", "input invalid", JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION);
        nama= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Name");

      }

  }
```

and this is my code for populating data from database into Jtable

```
public Vector viewPJG() throws RemoteException
{
    Vector vc = new Vector();
    Vector dataVector= new Vector();
    try{
         Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:PKKP","","");
        String view="select * from PJG";
        stmt=con.createStatement();
        result=stmt.executeQuery(view);
        int numcol=result.getMetaData().getColumnCount();
        System.out.println(numcol);
        while (result.next())
        {
            vc= new Vector();
            for(int i=1;i<=numcol;i++)
            {
                vc.addElement(result.getObject(i));
            }
            dataVector.addElement(vc);


        }


    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error at view "+ex.getMessage());

    }
return dataVector;
}
```

and here my code for populating from data database to jTable, in client's side:

```
 private void viewData()
{

    DefaultTableModel tabModel = (DefaultTableModel)  jTable1.getModel();
    tabModel.setColumnIdentifiers(kolom);
    tabModel.setRowCount(0);
    try {
        server serv3 = (server) Naming.lookup("rmi://127.0.0.1/server");
        Vector v = serv3.viewPJG();
        for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) 
        {
            Vector vtemp = (Vector) v.get(i);
            tabModel.addRow(vtemp);
        }


    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error at view:" + e.getMessage());
    }

}
```

i dont know what's wrong with my code, i have gooled but stil not found the solution, any one please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
        for(int i=1;i<=numcol;i++)
        {
            vc.addElement(result.getObject(i));
        }
```

to

```
        for(int i=1;i<=numcol;i++)
        {
            vc.addElement(String.valueOf(result.getObject(i)).trim());
        }
```

I suspect something is wrong in your `insertPJG` stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem to me like you have trailing spaces in your data. You should NOT store the data in the database with spaces.

So maybe you do something like:

```
prepstmt.setString(1, Nama_PJG.trim());
prepstmt.setString(2, Gugus.trim());
```

or

```
vc.addElement(result.getObject(i).toString().trim());
```

or

```
Gugus = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input Gugus").toString().trim();
```

We don't know where the problem is. It is up to you to do some basic debugging to determine where the spaces are coming from.

Also, follow Java naming conventions. Variable name should NOT start with an upper case character.